# How do I extract contents of a .bin file to any folder in linux?

Tags: linux, zip, bin, suse

I have a .bin file and would like to see its contents.Are there any commands to extract the contents ?

Comment: what type of file is this ? try `file <nameoffile.bin>`. Linux does not rely on file extensions like windooze does. It can be everything

Answer (score -2):

To do this move the file to a directory where you want to extract the file

```
mv <Bin-file> /<New-Directory>
```

after then give bin file execute permission

```
chmod +x /<New-Directory>/<Bin-File>
./<Bin-file>
```

write name of bin file with extension .bin

Comment: this would execute the bin file..I need to just extract its contents to a folder